# How to setup OAuth2 connection to Google Identity API within an Electron app safely with redirectUri pointing to localhost?

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-api, electron, google-identity

#### The context:

I'm trying to develop a desktop app with ElectronJS which needs access to Google APIs. As such, I want my users to be able to connect to their Google account via OAuth2.
As I use Electron, I have no safe way to store a "client-secret" and must use the "mobile app" method.

#### The problem:

Google keeps rejecting my redirect_uri:

[image]

#### The doc I followed:

The [official npm "google-auth-library" package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-auth-library) mentions the following regarding OAuth authentication for Electron apps ("OAuth2 with Installed Apps (Electron)" section) :

> If you're authenticating with OAuth2 from an installed application (like Electron), you may not want to embed your client_secret inside of the application sources. To work around this restriction, you can choose the iOS application type when creating your OAuth2 credentials in the Google Developers console

As doing so gave me the previously mentionned Error 400, I looked into [Google Identity documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#loopback-ip-address) and saw this regarding localhost redirection:

> Note that support for the loopback IP address redirect option on mobile apps is DEPRECATED.

#### My question:

At this point, I suspect that this is the reason Google is responding Error 400 to my requests (but I admit it could be my fault. I just don't understand what I do wrong as I feel like I follow the documentation strictly.)

If so, what are the possible ways to solve the issue ? Knowing that I have strictly 0 budget for this project and so I cannot afford to redirect to a domain I would buy or afford a server acting as proxy between my app and Google APIs.

#### (The code, if useful)

I use the "complete OAuth2 example" from `google-auth-library` except I changed the `OAuth2Client` constructor call to this, following the doc's recommandations:

```
const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client({
    clientId: "<the clientID of my project from Google API Console>",
    redirectUri: "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
})
```

In despair, I've tried a whole lot of different URL formats, but nothing works.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

**OAUTH BEHAVIOUR**

An OpenID Connect desktop app uses PKCE without a client secret. According to [RFC8252](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8252#section-7) it then receives the login response on either a loopback URL or via a private URI scheme notification.

The loopback option is fine for a desktop app but should not be used for a mobile app. Conversely, claimed HTTPS redirect URLs work for mobile apps but not desktop apps.

**TROUBLESHOOTING YOUR PROBLEM**

It is not clear whether your problem is caused by using a loopback URL or something else. To troubleshoot, you can use a couple of demo Electron apps of mine:

- [Loopback example](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.desktopsample1)
- [Private URI Scheme example](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.desktopsample.final)

In both cases, edit the `desktop.config.json` file in the root folder. Replace my AWS Cognito values with your Google values. Then run `npm start`. See if that gets you any further, and post any follow up questions.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try that on Monday and keep you updated.

Comment: Im running into the same issue with my project, Did you find any headway on how to resolve this yet ? I would be interested in the solution.